# How do I serialize binary data without the XML metatags?

Tags: c#, serialization

I am wanting to obfuscate some binary or text data that is in a binary array `byte[]`, I am able to accomplish converting into the string I want, but the `XmlSerializer` output includes the extra information.  Is there a different serializer that could be used to convert my data without having the XML tags appended?  If I need to deserialize it later, I will include the necessary tags.

```
byte[] baTest = new byte[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            baTest[i] = (byte) (i & 0xff);
        string MyTestString = ReadableXMLBinary(baTest);
        MessageBox.Show("My String is:\n" + MyTestString);

static public string ReadableXMLBinary(byte[] baIn)
        {
            StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
            XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof( byte[]));
            xser.Serialize(s, baIn);
            return s.ToString();
        }
```

Which outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><base64Binary>AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8gISIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0+P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXV5fYGFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6e3x9fn+AgYKDhIWGh4iJiouMjY6PkJGSk5SVlpeYmZqbnJ2en6ChoqOkpaanqKmqq6ytrq+wsbKztLW2t7i5uru8vb6/wMHCw8TFxsfIycrLzM3Oz9DR0tPU1dbX2Nna29zd3t/g4eLj5OXm5+jp6uvs7e7v8PHy8/T19vf4+fr7/P3+/w==</base64Binary>"
```

Basically, I want everything between the `<base64Binary>` tags.
I know I can strip out the text inside with little effort, but I thought there might be a clean solution that someone may suggest.

Comment: Do you want Binary Serialization?  It looks like you are taking binary serialization and then converting to a base 64 string.  But I do not understand why you have the xml ident in front of the data.

Comment: You need a root in your xml document, the `base64binary` serves that purpose. If you take that out, you no longer have xml. Can you clarify why you want to get rid of the root?

Comment: I do not want XML, it was just a way to get the binary data expanded in a better way than just hex ("0" - "F") values in the string.  I was going to write my own, but saw that the XML serialization did what I wanted for the binary data, but included the extra XML info I didn't.  The answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't want XML at all?

If that is the case, then use:
`string s = Convert.ToBase64String(baIn);`

and to convert back:
`byte[] baOut = Convert.FromBase64String(s);`